# Django: validate filefield within the form

Tags: python, django

I have seen a lot of posts that helped a lot but I am trying to write this validation in a slightly different way to verify that the type is 'text/csv' and that the size is smaller than 10mo but I cannot get it to work

Here is what my forms.py look like:

```
class ETL(forms.Form):
    Historical = forms.FileField()
    Pre_processing = forms.FileField()
    Supplier = forms.FileField()
    parameters = forms.FileField()



    def process_data(self, url, *args, **kwargs):
"""
        historical data checkout
        """
        content = self.cleaned_data['Historical']
        content_type = content.content_type.split('/')[0]
        if content_type in settings.CONTENT_TYPES and content.size > settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE:
            fh = io.TextIOWrapper(self.cleaned_data['Historical'].file)

                #raise forms.ValidationError(_('Please keep filesize under %s. Current filesize %s') % (filesizeformat(settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE), filesizeformat(content.file.size)))        
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('File type is not supported, check type and size'))


        """
        pre-procesing data checkout
        """
        content = self.cleaned_data['Pre_processing']
        content_type = content.content_type.split('/')[0]
        if content_type in settings.CONTENT_TYPES and content.size > settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE:
            #if content.size > settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE:
            fpp = io.TextIOWrapper(self.cleaned_data['Pre_processing'].file)

                #raise forms.ValidationError(_('Please keep filesize under %s. Current filesize %s') % (filesizeformat(settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE), filesizeformat(content.file.size)))

        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('File type is not supported'))



        """
        supplier data checkout
        """
        content = self.cleaned_data['Supplier']
        content_type = content.content_type.split('/')[0]
        if content_type in settings.CONTENT_TYPES and content.size > settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE:
            fs = io.TextIOWrapper(self.cleaned_data['Supplier'].file)

                #raise forms.ValidationError(_('Please keep filesize under %s. Current filesize %s') % (filesizeformat(settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE), filesizeformat(content.file.size)))

        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('File type is not supported'))

"""
        parameters data checkout
        """
        content = self.cleaned_data['parameters']
        content_type = content.content_type.split('/')[0]
        if content_type in settings.CONTENT_TYPES and content.size > settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE:
            fp = io.TextIOWrapper(self.cleaned_data['parameters'].file)

                #raise forms.ValidationError(_('Please keep filesize under %s. Current filesize %s') % (filesizeformat(settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE), filesizeformat(content.file.size)))

        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('File type is not supported'))


 data = pd.read_csv(fpp)
 data2 = pd.read_csv(fs)
```

and then my view.py is as the following:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class Getfiles(LoginRequiredMixin,FormView):
    template_name = 'upload.html'
    form_class = ETL
    success_url ='dash.html'



    def form_valid(self, form):
        url = self.request.build_absolute_uri()

        if form.is_valid():

            logger.debug('data acquired')
            form.process_data(url)
            logger.debug('data has been processed')

            return super().form_valid(form)
        else:
            return render(request, 'upload.html')
```

and when I upload the proper files to test it out, I get the following error:

```
   raise forms.ValidationError(_('File type is not supported, check type and size'))
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['File type is not supported, check type and size']
```

and in my settings.py I have:

```
CONTENT_TYPES = 'text/csv'
MAX_UPLOAD_FILE_SIZE = 10485760
```

I am thinking that the issue is within the "if statement and return something that can be read in pd.DataFrame(). I have spent all day on it but I cannot find a way to solve it on my own

Comment: have you checked what values the following variables have; `content_type ` , `content.size`, `self.cleaned_data['Historical']` and `self.cleaned_data['Historical'].file` ?

Comment: What do you mean by what value they have, do you mean type?

Comment: i mean the value / object / content of the variable, but the type might also help

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is mismatched, may be you want to do something like this

```
if content_type in settings.CONTENT_TYPES 
    if content.size < settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE:
        fs = io.TextIOWrapper(self.cleaned_data['Supplier'].file)
    else:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_('Please keep filesize under %s. Current filesize %s') % (filesizeformat(settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE), filesizeformat(content.file.size)))
else:
    raise forms.ValidationError(_('File type is not supported'))
```

Same goes to others as well (Historical, Pre_processing, parameters)

Comment: thank you for correcting me! it helps but when I try uploading a wrong file type, the error does not get caught until passing in the pd.csv reader